# ID value not being generated automatically

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am trying to create a simple ToDo object using Spring Data JPA framework, but am not able to do so.

When I am calling save method on my repository, I am getting SQL exception that value of ID is null. Below if the code of my ToDo class.

```
  package demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by MJ on 12/19/2016.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="TODOS")
public class ToDo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private String title;

    public ToDo(String description, String title){
        this.description = description;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

As per my understanding, this should generate the ID on it's own. But am not sure what I am missing. Can anyone help?

This is how I am creating the object of this class and trying to save it in DB:

```
ToDo toDo = new ToDo("First","TODO");
repository.save(toDo);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: no need to add @Column for the id. also IDENTITY does not work on every db as i know. does it work if you set GenerationType.AUTO ?

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Tried without using @Coulumn and GenerationType.AUTO but got same error, hence tried this solution.

Comment: Using MySql Database.

Comment: hwo did you create the todos table? by hibernate or manually?

Comment: IDENTITY for MySQL will mean that AUTO_INCREMENT will be the COLUMN type (schema generated). Have you let the JPA provider generate the schema? And then look at what SQL is issued for your insert. aka debugging

Comment: I created the table manually. Should I mark the ID column as Auto_Increment and try again?

Comment: YES, definitely

Comment: Done. This fixed the issue, thanks. Could you post this as answer? I'd accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change id column as Auto Increment in DB

Comment: AUTO simply says leave it to the JPA provider to choose the strategy. It does NOT guarantee any particular one will be used (and if you had set the column to AUTO_INCREMENT and the provider chose TABLE then it would fail). His original choice of IDENTITY ought to be fine for MySQL ... if he has AUTO_INCREMENT on the column